# How to create Source that results in empty node sequence

Tags: xslt, saxon

Is there a way to create a [`javax.xml.transform.Source`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) implementation that *Saxon 10* will interpret as an *empty node sequence*. There are various ways of constructing a `Source` that is a document node that has no children, i.e. an empty document, but in this case the `Source` should return an empty node sequence.

Use case for this is an [`javax.xml.transform.URIResolver`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/transform/URIResolver.html) implementation that is able to return a `Source` for an empty document node sequence, when [XSLT `document()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-document) is used. This allows the `URIResolver` to mimic a *recoverable error* behaviour when the target resource is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sorry, I think I led you up the garden path on this one. It can't be done; a Source must either resolve to a single Node, or fail.

Comment: Even if you have a custom `NodeInfo` implementation that returns `true` for `isNilled()`, the output is still a non-empty document nodes sequence.